# Is there any way of controlling the exam ID?

Tags: r, r-exams

We are using a loop with `exams2nops` to produce several exam versions of the same exam, but with different databases generated in an introduction file which is added to the final PDF produced by the `exams2nops` function. However, each loop produces an exam with the same exam IDs, is any way of controlling the ID giving to each exam?

So, what we need is to customize the generation of the exam ID with corresponding rds file for later `nops_eval`.

Comment: Could you show us the code you're currently running?

Comment: Yes, I described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187933/7773713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some limited control, see argument `startid`.

In general the ID is always composed as `yymmddxxxxx`, where `yy` is the year of the date of the exam, `mm` the month, `dd` the day, and `xxxxx` is a consecutive ID starting from `00001` by default. However, with `startid` you can start from a different initial ID.

For example, `exams2nops(..., date = "2021-01-20")` starts with `21012000001` while `exams2nops(..., date = "2021-01-20", startid = 42)` starts with `21012000042`.

Personally, when I mix less than 10 different batches of NOPS exams, I used `startid = 1`, `startid = 10001`, `startid = 20001`, etc.

Note also that you can `nops_eval()` all of these together then, you just need to manually merge the .rds files produced by them. To do so, `readRDS()` each .rds file into some object, combine all objects with `c()`, and `saveRDS()` into a new .rds file that you use subsequently. If you want to merge a large number of .rds files in the current working directory, you can use the following code:

```
## readRDS all *.rds files in the current working directory
x <- lapply(Sys.glob("*.rds"), readRDS)

## combine all resulting lists
y <- do.call("c", x)

## saveRDS into a single .rds file
saveRDS(y, "all.rds")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Achim !!!

This fits well our solution (specially with the .rds file merge).

Even so, I believe `exams` would benefit of having a `extype: intro` where a general introduction and dataset could be randomly generated and then used in the following exercises. Please consider this suggestion (and next time at Innsbruck, beer is on me!)

Warm regards,

João